# Make thread execute function from other class

Tags: java

So I have this thread:

```
public static class Update implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        Timer tm;

       tm = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Clienti cl = new Clienti();
            cl.populateTable();
            }
        });

    tm.start();

    }
}
```

And I am running it from another package(I'm doing this as an experiment). However, when trying the program out, it seems that the populateTable(); function is working inside the Update class only? I have tried creating this class inside the Clienti class and it works perfectly, however this seems to have a few problems. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the populateTable() method:

```
public void populateTable(){
        MyQuery mq = new MyQuery();
        ArrayList<GetClass> list = mq.BindTable();
        String[] columnName = {"ID","Picture","Name","Age","Sex"};
        Object[][] rows = new Object[list.size()][5];
        int i;


        for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            rows[i][0] = list.get(i).getId();

            if(list.get(i).getPicture() != null){

             ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(list.get(i).getPicture()).getImage()
             .getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH) );   

            rows[i][1] = image;
            }
            else{
                rows[i][1] = null;
            }

            rows[i][2] = list.get(i).getName();
            rows[i][3] = list.get(i).getAge();
            rows[i][4] = list.get(i).getSex();

        }

        TheModel model = new TheModel(rows, columnName);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.setRowHeight(50);
        table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(150);
```

Comment: what few problems?

Comment: It's not updating the JTable @Luminous_Dev

Comment: populateTable method works? YOU need to give us more codes, the code looks fine, Im sure its the way you have structured the thread and at the moment, this thread is not talking to your GUI

Comment: @Luminous_Dev the populateTable method works , I want it to make to talk to my GUI, as i said in the post. <- This is what I need

Comment: Just with that code, its not helping anyone to find problem, you need to give us more codes, perhaps populateTable() method I dont think this method talks directly to UI updating to UI should be in a seperate UI controller

Comment: I will also add the populateTable method if that helps you. What made me question this was the fact that it worked when i made this class inside the Clienti class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142218/discussion-between-chor-may-and-luminous-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After chatting with Luminous_Dev, he figured out the answer. I added this to the Update thread:

```
private Clienti clienti;
public Update(Clienti clienti){
    this.clienti = clienti;
}
```

And also changed

```
Clienti cl = new Clienti();
        cl.populateTable();
```

with `clienti.populateTable();` and added a "this" inside the constructor pharanteses where I create the thread.